# Agda: Derive equality *and* AVL dicts in the same program?

Tags: dictionary, reflection, functional-programming, agda, dependent-type

I'm doing some PL theory work in Agda, and I've run into this situation

- I need some kind of dictionary (like the Stdlib AVL trees) to encode finite maps.
- I need to derive equality for my types, since they have many constructors and a pairwise comparison is tedious.

[Agda-prelude](https://github.com/UlfNorell/agda-prelude), provides the second but not the first, and the stdlib provides the first but not the second. The two are not compatible.

Are there existing libraries I can use that will give me both functionalities without conflicts? I'm not worried about performance, so if the finite maps are list-backed that's fine, but I'd prefer to not prove a bunch of theorems about them manually.

Comment: I have a [library](https://github.com/effectfully/Generic) that can derive equality and is compatible with the standard one, but I don't really know whether it's able to derive equality for Agda's AVL trees. And I can't figure this out, because I'm far away from my machine and [unable](https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/2529) to install Agda on an available one. I don't even know whether the library type checks with the recent version of Agda. So it's probably a waste of time to try it. Maybe try to ask Ulf Norell to add AVL trees to his prelude?

Comment: @user3237465 Thanks, that looks like just what I want! I don't actually need Eq for AVL, I just need to be able to use AVL in general (you can't import stdlib at all if using prelude). So your library looks perfect! I've tried using it, and I am getting a type error in 2.5.2. There's an open issue on your GH, though I realize you're not in a position to fix it, so I'll try debugging it.